# Best method filtering data with MySQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find the best method to filter some data with mysql and php
so basically i have a table for user and his access (1->yes and 0->no)

[image]

and another table for the data I need to filter based on his access like below:
[image]

What I am doing at the moment is that i am reading all items from data table then using PHP looping around all data and using if else to keep an item or not

This is working just fine as of speed however more filtering might be needed which will make the if else statement bigger and complicated..
Any good ideas or techniques ?

Comment: Can you post your existing SQL queries?

Comment: The best method is normalisation

Answer (score 2):

You should normalize the access table to something like this:

LocationAccess:

```
user    location
----    --------
adam    CountryA
adam    CountryB
alice   CountryB
alice   CountryC
```

TypeAccess:

```
user    type
----    ----
adam    A
adam    B
adam    C
alice   A
alice   C
```

Then you can join the tables:

```
SELECT l.user, data.item
FROM data 
JOIN LocationAccess AS l ON l.location = d.location
JOIN TypeAccess AS t ON t.type = d.type AND t.user = l.user
```